# Triangular Numbers Test Revision

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm doing some Maths Revision for an upcoming test. I'm not sure how to work this out.

nth triangular number = $ \dfrac {n(n + 1)} 2 $

Example: 3rd triangular number = 3/2 (3 + 1)

I'm trying to find out the 10th number in the sequence. How do you work that out? I've tried doing 10 + 1 = 11 (because n + 1) than 10/2 = 1/5 = as decimal 0.2 (because n/2) than 0.2 * 11 but apparently the 10th number in the sequence is 55. How is that?

And how would you work out the 100th number in the sequence...

P.S. When the slashed numbers are fractions.

Comment: I'm not sure how to work it out, I've tried doing all sorts of things but it's not coming out as 55, please explain and be easy on the answers. Thanks!

Comment: $\frac{10}{2} = 5.$ So then $5 \cdot 11 = 55$.

Comment: Oh right!!!!!! thanks :)

Comment: Incidentally, I recommend writing it as $n(n+1)/2$ to avoid confusion about the possibility that, e.g, you're supposed to be dividing $n$ by $2(n+1)$.

Answer (score 2):

If we write this as $T(n) = \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$ instead of $T(n) = \dfrac {n}{2}\cdot (n+1)$ or more confusing still, instead of $T(n) = n/2(n+1)$, we'll have less confusion:

$$T(n) = \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2} \implies  T(10) = \frac{10(11)}{2} =\frac{110}{2}= 55$$

Note that $2$ will *always* divide *exactly one* of $\,n\,$ or $\,(n+1),\,$ where $n$ is ***any*** natural number, so $T(n)$ will always be an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of got it now. I know what I did wrong I changed $2 \over 10$ (10th number in the sequence) into a decimal which I should have left as 5. So $5 \times 11 = 55$.

Comment: Problems involving integers are usually better left as integers instead of decimals.  Often the decimals are not exact (like $1/3$) and that will show up as things not being equal (like $3*(1/3) \neq 1$)

Comment: It's not so much that you changed it to a decimal as that you _flipped_ it - you started with $\dfrac{10}{2}$, turned that into $\dfrac{1}{5}$ and then turned _that_ into $0.2$ - but the problem wasn't turning $\dfrac15$ into $0.2$, but turning $\dfrac{10}{2}$ into $\dfrac15$, because those two are entirely different values.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thanks, i was confused with that, it's meant to be 5/1 I think whcih 5 devided by 1 = 5